# Not Found The requested URL /emr/login was not found on this server. in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I Started One New Project in Laravel. After Installed and Updated the Composer. I Run My Project. Home Page is Display. I create and goto Login Page of my Project It. Display

> Not Found The requested URL /emr/login was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

How do Solve It.

Code in controllers

```
class AuthController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('dashboard')));

    }


    public function userlog() {
        return View::make('login',array('metatitle' => 'Register'));
    }
}
```

route file :

```
Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('login');
    });

Route::get('login','AuthController@userlog');
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should point your web server (Apache, for example) to the `public` directory of your Laravel project.

Then use this route:

```
Route::get('emr/login','AuthController@userlog');
```

**Or** go to `/login` in your browser.

You're using `/emr/login` path, but you do not have right route for it, that's because it doesn't work.

Comment: It's Not Working.. emr is Project Folder Name.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. The thing is you should point your web server to `public` directory of your `emr` directory, after that restart web server. Please try it and tell me is it working or not.

Comment: I got Following Error in Terminal                                                                                                              : Cannot create cache directory /home/w3cert/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/w3cert/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

Comment: Set write permissions on `/storage` folder. For Windows it's: www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7

Comment: I am using ubuntu Os

Comment: For Ubuntu, go to the Laravel project directory and use: `chmod -R 777 storage`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@userlog');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.